# Unable to load same module template file in same module template

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am working on Prestashop module. In this module I have a lengthy html template. So, I am breaking it into smaller sub template.

Now, I have a base template file in which I am including my all sub template file.

My Template Directory is given below:

```
/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/base.tpl  
/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/upper_section.tpl  
/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/middle_section.tpl  
/modules/my_module/views/templates/front/bottom_section.tpl
```

Now, I am including all the above template file in base.tpl as shown in below code:

```
{include file='upper_section.tpl'}  
{include file='middle_section.tpl'}  
{include file='bottom_section.tpl'}
```

When I run my fron controller of module, then prestashop is giving me error as "Unable to Load Template upper_section.tpl".

I have also tried by giving relative as well as absolute path for template file but everytime I am getting the same error.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Change your includes to include files from current folder.

```
{include file='./upper_section.tpl'}  
{include file='./middle_section.tpl'}  
{include file='./bottom_section.tpl'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way for you.

```
{include file='module:my_module/views/upper_section.tpl'}
```